# Update an Image in Grails Database

Tags: image, grails, groovy

i've got a domain class in which i can store images. Currently i can create a database entry and if wanted upload an image. Now i want to change the update method in my DomainController. The method should handle a change of the image, the old one has to be replaced. And there should be a function to delete the image.

My DomainController def update(Class classInstance) -->

```
    @Transactional
def update(Comment commentInstance) {
    if (commentInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (!commentInstance.imageData){
        def file = request.getFile('file')
        if(file.empty) {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        } else {
            commentInstance.imageData = file.getBytes()
            commentInstance.imageName = file.originalFilename
            commentInstance.comment = params.comment
            commentInstance.feedback = Feedback.get(params.feedback.id)
            commentInstance.user = User.get(params.user.id)

        }
    }
    else
        print "not set yet"

    if (commentInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond commentInstance.errors, view: 'trash'
        return
    }

    commentInstance.save flush: true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Comment.label', default: 'Comment'), commentInstance.id])
            redirect commentInstance
        }
        '*' { respond commentInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

segment of my edit.gsp -->

```
    <g:if test="${commentInstance?.imageData}">
    <img src="${createLink(controller: "comment", field:"imageData", action:'showImage', id:"${commentInstance.id}")}" width="100"/>
    <br><g:message code="${commentInstance.imageName}" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <asset:image src="no_img.png" alt="no_img" width="100"/>
</g:else>
<g:fieldValue bean="${fileInstance}" field="imageName" />

<g:uploadForm controller="comment" action="update" datatype="file">
<input type="file" name="imageData" />
</g:uploadForm>

<g:form url="[resource: commentInstance, action: 'update']" method="PUT">
    <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${commentInstance?.version}"/>
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update"
                        value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}"/>
    </fieldset>

</g:form>
```

When i try to upload an image via the update method i get this error:

> No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter$HttpMethodRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]
>   Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON(). Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter$HttpMethodRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]
>   Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()

How i need to edit my controller method to handle this?

Greets Tim

Comment: `def file = request.getFile('file')` should be `def file = request.getFile('imageData')`. You should also have a single form to submit. More forms are needed only if you want to make AJAX-like file upload

Comment: I didn't edited the form, but change 'file' to 'imageData' unfortunately doesn't work..

Comment: that alone doesn't help. you must either merge both forms into a single one, or submit the `<g:uploadForm controller="comment" action="update" datatype="file">` separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the corrections and read my `//comments` below

```
 def updateImage(){ // no need for the command object, you need the file itself and the id
    Comment commentInstance = Comment.get params.id
    if( !commentInstance ){
      response.sendError 404 // or some other error signalling
      return
    }
    if(commentInstance.imageData == null){ // I would omit this if, the image should be replaced anyway
        def file = request.getFile('imageData') // must be imageData, according to your GSP
        if(file.empty) {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        } else {
            commentInstance.imageData = file.bytes
            commentInstance.imageName = file.originalFilename
            commentInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        }
    } else {
        print "something else"
    }

    redirect (action:'index')
}
```

and GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm controller="comment" action="updateImage" datatype="file">
  <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${commentInstance.id}"/>
  ...
</g:uploadForm>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've edited the form a little bit. My error was because the static allowedMethods. 
I added my method to the static allowedMethods and edited my upload form like this
 <g:uploadForm url="[resource: commentInstance, action:'updateImage']" method="PUT" datatype="file">
        <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${commentInstance.id}"/>

Comment: I've same problem here, but the solution doesn't work with PUT. The only way is to use always the POST method, otherwise the error always arises.

Answer (score 0):

In the GSP action name is update and the action created in controller is updateImage it seems like right method is not called.